# need help in formatting a particular type of String in java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I am new in java String formatting concept so need help. I have a string something like [MALE] and i need remove those braces and get MALE. How to get it done?

Comment: i don't know much about Java, but you can try substring type function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do..

```
yourString=yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1)
```

Comment: @ihasan Kocak according to the question asked i provided the answer, in your case you need different code.

Comment: @ihasan Kocak this will do what you looking for: yourString=yourString.replace("yourCharacterWantToRemove","");

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a `String` in java so you will need to use a `StringBuilder`. If you want to use the atomic bomb, use a regular expression. Otherwise just checkout the `StringBuilder` methods [in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and do what you wish.

You can turn it back to a String afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Remove {
public static void main(String [] args){
    String string = "[MALE]";
    string = string.replaceAll("\\[", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\]", "");
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringBuilder

```
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
 sb.deleteCharAt(sb.indexOf("["));
 sb.deleteCharAt(sb.indexOf("]"));
```

For String(This looks like a workaround):

```
 String s="[SBD]";
  s=  s.replace("[","");
   s= s.replace("]","");
```

Please note that if more than one "[" or "]" it will replace all occurences.

Comment: Ui ... The "String only" answer is simply wrong. A String is immutable, so the replace method does not change it. It returns a new String that has the replacements.